# No añadir elementos repetidos a una lista

Tags: java, android, lista

Tengo un método que recorre unos usuarios, los cuales tienen diferentes recursos, hasta ahí todo bien, pero quiero evitar que si en dos usuarios detecta que hay dos elementos iguales, no añada ninguno de los dos a la lista, los omita, pero no lo consigo, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
@NotNull
    public static HashSet<File> listItemsForUserInDirectoryAtPath(int level, String path) {
        List<User> usersLogged = SessionManager.sharedInstance().getUsersLogued();
        File contentResourcesFolderPath = new File(path);
        HashSet<Project> projectHashSet = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<File> resourcesFilesFromContentFolder = new HashSet<>(
                Arrays.asList(contentResourcesFolderPath.listFiles())
        );
        HashSet<File> resourcesFilesFiltered = new HashSet<>();
        for (User userLogged: usersLogged) {
            ArrayList<Class> classesForAllUserSelected = Content
                    .sharedInstance()
                    .getClassesForUser(
                            userLogged,
                            level
                    );
            for (Class class: classesForAllUserSelected) {
                for (Subject subject: class.getSubjects()) {
                    projectHashSet.addAll(subject.getProjects());
                }
            }
        }
        for (Project project: projectHashSet) {
            for (Resource resource: project.getResources()) {
                if (resource.isAvailable()) {
                    for (File file : resourcesFilesFromContentFolder) {
                        if (file.getName().equals(resource.getNameFileInDisc())) {
                            resourcesFilesFiltered.add(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resourcesFilesFiltered;
    }
```

Solo necesito eso, que la lista projectHashSet no contenga los elementos repetidos, pero no consigo como hacerlo, lo he intentado con HashSet pero claro, esto me mete al menos uno de ellos.

Comment: En este caso el problema principalmente es cuando previamente insertaste un elemento y tratas de insertar uno igual, ambos los debería eliminar de la lista , es así?, ¿En que parte especificamente estas insertando los elementos?

Comment: @Jorgesys lo que tengo aquí es un método que recorre una lista de usuarios y de ellos los recorro para sacar todas sus clases. Es en la linea:                     projectHashSet.addAll(subject.getProjects()); donde quiero que solo se añadan aquellos elementos no repetidos, sacando de ahi todos los que si estén repetidos, pero que no incluya ni el repetido ni el original, que solo queden los elementos unicos.